# Find most similar shapes in Python

Tags: python, vector, comparison, virtual-keyboard, n900

I am working on a virtual keyboard, similar to Swype (but for a platform it doesn't support). Basically, what it does (for those not familiar) is you move your finger over the keys without lifting it off for each word. So what I need to do is compare the shape drawn to the shape of each word in the wordlist, and use the most similar one. My problem is: How do I find the most similar shape?

Edit: I tried the Python implementation of the $1 recognizer, but it takes nearly 7 minutes to parse my 32,000 word wordlist. Is there a way I can speed this up (or at least precompute it)? Here is what I am using to generate it:

```
self.keylayout = ["qwertyuiop","asdfghjkl;","zxcvbnm,."]
for i in wl:
    points = []
    for j in i:
        if j.lower() in self.keylayout[0]:
            points.append((40, self.keylayout[0].index(j.lower())*48+24))
        elif j.lower() in self.keylayout[1]:
            points.append((120, self.keylayout[1].index(j.lower())*48+24))
        elif j.lower() in self.kl[2]:
            points.append((200, self.keylayout[2].index(j.lower())*48+24))
    self.rec = Recognizer()
    self.rec.addTemplate(i, points)
```

Comment: Using the $1 recogniser, can you just pickle `points[]`? or your `self.rec`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had written this sometime back. A slightly different approach, It is pretty fast. hope it helps..

http://krishnabharadwaj.info/how-swype-works/

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! This works much better than what I had!

Comment: I am glad you found it useful :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [$1 Unistroke Recognizer in JavaScript](http://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/). It is badass.

Comment: Another cool one, this is for LaTeX symbols: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: I tried to understand the latex one but coudn't. There is a python version of the $1 recognizer though.